# INNER JOIN with 3 tables using Count(*) function

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, count, inner-join

I am having a problem getting my inner join to work when using the count function, as it says 'Count function requires at least 1 argument'. Below is my code from the aspx.cs file. Thanks for any help in advance:)

[Code for INNER Join issue][1]

```
 protected void CalculateNums_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UniString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    String CIT = "1";

    myConnection.Open();

    String findCIT = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT COUNT(class.class_id, class.pathway_year_id, classlist.classlist_id, classlist.class_id, classlist.user_id,pathway_years.id, pathway_years.pathway_id, pathways.id, pathways.pathway) AS findCITString FROM class INNER JOIN classlist ON classlist.class_id = class.class_id INNER JOIN pathway_years ON pathway_years.id = class.pathway_year_id INNER JOIN pathways ON pathways.id = pathway_years.pathway_id WHERE pathways.id = '" + CIT+"')t";


    SqlCommand findCITCommand = new SqlCommand(findCIT, myConnection);

    Int32 findCITString = Convert.ToInt32(findCITCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    myConnection.Close();

    numInCIT.Text = Convert.ToString(findCITString);
}
```

[ErrorAfterDistinct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8D4r.png)

```
String findCIT = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT class.class_id, class.pathway_year_id, classlist.classlist_id, classlist.class_id,      classlist.user_id, pathway_years.id, pathway_years.pathway_id, pathways.id, pathways.pathway FROM class INNER JOIN classlist ON classlist.class_id = class.class_id INNER JOIN pathway_years ON pathway_years.id = class.pathway_year_id INNER JOIN pathways ON pathways.id = pathway_years.pathway_id WHERE pathways.id = '" + CIT + "') as t";
```

Comment: The query looks fine.  Moreover, AFAIK, `Count function requires at least 1 argument` doesn't look like a MySQL error message.

Comment: I have updated the question with an image of the error if this makes it any clearer? @ForguesR

Comment: Fixed the tags in your question.  Have a look at my answer.  If you still have a problem with your query please tell me.

Comment: I tried using this...and have updated my error photo after I have changed to the distinct...it may be a problem with my inner join? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Please update the code extract, it will be much more helpful.

Comment: I have updated this now, sorry I am new to this:)

Comment: Please look at the edit section in my answer,

Comment: Thanks I will try that in the morning...it is 4am here so I'll update later:) Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using MySQL but MSSQL : "Count function requires at least 1 argument" is a MSSQL error message.

With MSSQL you have to provide only one argument for a [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx).  Here is the query you might be looking for :

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
  FROM 
    (SELECT 
       DISTINCT class.class_id,
                class.pathway_year_id,
                classlist.classlist_id,
                classlist.class_id,
                classlist.user_id,
                pathway_years.id,
                pathway_years.pathway_id,
                pathways.id,
                pathways.pathway
    FROM class
    INNER JOIN classlist ON classlist.class_id = class.class_id 
    INNER JOIN pathway_years ON pathway_years.id = class.pathway_year_id 
    INNER JOIN pathways ON pathways.id = pathway_years.pathway_id 
    WHERE pathways.id = '" + CIT+"') as t
```

Notice the use of `DISTINCT` in the inner query instead of `COUNT()`.

**Edit :**

It is hard to understand what you want to do with this query.  Anyway, it still doesn't work because some column names in the inner query are used twice, like `class_id`.

Here is how I would rewrite it :

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM class
INNER JOIN classlist ON classlist.class_id = class.class_id
INNER JOIN pathway_years ON pathway_years.id = class.pathway_year_id
INNER JOIN pathways ON pathways.id = pathway_years.pathway_id
WHERE
  pathways.id = '" + CIT + "'
GROUP BY
  class.class_id,
  class.pathway_year_id,
  classlist.classlist_id,
  classlist.class_id,
  classlist.user_id,
  pathway_years.id,
  pathway_years.pathway_id,
  pathways.id,
  pathways.pathway
```